# How to use Google on terminal?

Tags: terminal

This maybe some ridiculous, but sometimes I need to work on server and there was no X interface. How to use Google and its search results in Unix-like terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of terminal-web-browsers out there, if that's what you're asking. links2 is probably the most famous.

http://links.twibright.com/

[And here comes the ultimate-everything-terminal-based-daily-life-programs.](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2007/05/21/a-day-without-x/)